# I can't seem to be able to change the thumbnail crop settings in wp e-commerce

Tags: wordpress, plugins, e-commerce, thumbnails, product

As described in the title, I cant for the life of me find a way to change the thumbnail crop settings in wp e-commerce. By default, it is set to show the centre of the picture. However, I would like to make the cropped thumbnail include the top part of the picture.

I already know how to do this within the Wordpress' built in featured images code. For those that stumble across this post and don't know how to do this, you can find it in [This Post](http://shailan.com/781/how-to-change-post-thumbnail-crop-position-in-wordpress/).  I have tried the above and wp e-commerce does not seem to use the same thumbnail cropping function as core Wordpress.

```
$s_x = 0; // floor( ($orig_w - $crop_w) / 2 );
$s_y = 0; // floor( ($orig_h - $crop_h) / 2 );
```

After commenting the code, this would have worked if it was with the post thumbnails, but doesn't work with the WP e-commerce thumbnails.

I would appreciate any kind of help if anyone has come across a way to do this.

Seedorf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oops. Ignore this question. The change which I made appeared to have worked. I had to fully reset the cache to make it work though I think. For those that are looking for a similar solution, the above code i posted in my question above can be found in the media.php. in the WP includes files